# About the ramification divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-curves

I am reading about Hurwitz's theorem

``Let $\varphi : C' \to C$ be a surjective morphism of irreducible smooth projective curves over $k$ of genus $g(C')$ and $g(C)$. Then we have 
$$2g(C') - 2 = \deg (\varphi ) (2g(C) - 2) +  \deg (R_{\varphi}) $$ where $R_{\varphi}$ is  the ramification divisor of $\varphi$.''

However, I haven't yet understood really  about the ramification divisor and I had some difficulties to determinate $R_{\varphi}$. In particular, if $C' \equiv C \equiv \mathbb{P^1}$ then $R_{\varphi} = \sum\limits_{x \in C'} (e_x  -1)$. Is this true?

**My question:** How is the dependence of the ramification divisor of surjective morphism to its ramification indexes?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think that the discussion on this point in Hartshorne is very nice.  Have a look.

Comment: That expression for the degree of the ramification divisor is true whenever $\varphi$ is separable.